# PostgreSQL non-daemon

Tags: linux, postgresql, foreman

I want foreman to manage my Postgres database sever in development but I can't figure out how to run Postgres as a non-daemon.

I installed Postgres using
`sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib` as per the instructions  here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL.

After running `postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data`, I get a `command not found` error.

Anyone know why my `postgres` command is not found/available and/or if this is the right command?

Comment: I don't know where you got the `postgres` command idea from, but the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/creating-cluster.html) suggests to use either `initdb` or `pg_ctl`.

Comment: `initdb` and `pg_ctl` are not found either. I can start the database using `sudo service postgresql start` though.

Comment: Have a look in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/`. You may want to search or ask at the Ubuntu SE or help why these commands are not linked to eg `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: To answer the question from my previous comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/371737/install-postgresql-why-is-initdb-unavailable . Use the `postgres` account. But they are generally not accessible, as these commands are normally not needed (as, indeed, you can use `service` or `systemctl`).

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct and should work just fine as long as you do it as PostgreSQL operating system user.

Your error message just means that the `postgres` executable is not found in the `PATH`; you can get around that by using its absolute path.